Create OpenAPI examples from OpenAPI ruleset?
I'm wondering if there are extensions, libraries or applications which can help create examples from OpenAPI rulesets used for linting OpenAPI specifications.
I've been googling for "generate examples specification from openapi ruleset", what mainly comes up is the OpenAPI specification itself.
Example ruleset:
extends: spectral:oas
rules:
  rule-important-info-fields:
    description: Absolutely must have the info information
    message: "Missing the {{property}}"
    given: "$.info"
    severity: error
    then:
     - field: "title"
       function: truthy
     - field: "description"
       function: truthy
     - field: "version"
       function: truthy
 
  rule-path-description:
    description: Each operation must have a description which cannot be empty.
    given: $.paths.[*][get,post,put,delete,options]
    severity: error
    then:
      field: description
      function: truthy
 
  rule-camel-case-operation-id:
    description: OperationId should be pascalCased.
    type: style
    given: $.paths.[*][get,post,put,delete,options]
    then:
      field: operationId
      function: casing
      functionOptions:
        type: pascal
  
  rule-camel-case-parameter-name:
    description: Parameter name should be camelCased.
    message: "The value '{{value}}' should be camel cased."
    type: style
    given: $.paths.[*][get,post,put,delete,options].parameters[*]
    severity: error
    resolved: false
    then:
      field: name
      function: casing
      functionOptions:
        type: camel
 
  rule-operation-singular-tag:
    description: Operations must have at least one tag value.
    type: style
    given: $.paths.[*][get,post,put,delete,options]
    severity: error
    then:
      field: tags
      function: length
      functionOptions:
        min: 1
 
  rule-path-no-trailing-slash:
    description: Paths should not end with `#/`.
    type: style
    given: "$.paths[*]~"
    severity: error
    then:
      function: pattern
      functionOptions:
        notMatch: ".+\/$"
 
  rule-path-lower-case-id:
    description: Resource identifier in path should be represented as 'xxxId', eg CustomerId.
    type: style
    given: "$.paths[*]~"
    severity: error
    then:
      function: pattern
      functionOptions:
        notMatch: "{\\w*id}"
 
  oas3-api-servers: error

Even though tools such as Spectral gives a list of missing fields and values, it would be nice to generate new examples whenever the ruleset changes.

I'm not aware of any tools that can do that, so you'll probably have to write something yourself or maintain the examples manually.

The rules don't have any context or reference to the actual schema.  How would you define a valid example without that link?

Good question. I was looking for the reason why it wouldn't work and why it had not ben done before.
